# Multivariate/single output LSTM classification : Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to train a LSTM model using Keras but when I try to compile the model I get this error :
"Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor"

My training set is of shape (14943, 7, 12), which means 14943 samples of shape 7 (timesteps), 12 (nb of features considered).Here is my code:

```
    X_train,y_train = split_sequence_multi(train_data,features_considered,7, 1)
    X_train,y_train= array(X_train),array(y_train)


    # reshape from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features]

    X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))    
    print(X_train.shape)

    # define model
    model = Sequential()

    if n_steps_out == 1:

        model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))

    else:

        model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
        #model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
        model.add(LSTM(150, activation='relu'))
        #model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))


    model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['Precision','Recall','AUC'])
```

Here is the full error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-5f4a1a6a6078> in <module>
     46 
     47     model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
---> 48     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['Precision','Recall','AUC'])
     49 
     50 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    220             skip_target_masks=[l is None for l in self.loss_functions],
    221             sample_weights=self.sample_weights,
--> 222             masks=masks)
    223 
    224         # Compute total loss.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _handle_metrics(self, outputs, targets, skip_target_masks, sample_weights, masks)
    869 
    870                 self._handle_per_output_metrics(
--> 871                     self._per_output_metrics[i], target, output, output_mask)
    872                 self._handle_per_output_metrics(
    873                     self._per_output_weighted_metrics[i],

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _handle_per_output_metrics(self, metrics_dict, y_true, y_pred, mask, weights)
    840             with K.name_scope(metric_name):
    841                 training_utils.call_metric_function(
--> 842                     metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)
    843 
    844     def _handle_metrics(self,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in call_metric_function(metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
   1031 
   1032     if y_pred is not None:
-> 1033         update_ops = metric_fn.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights)
   1034         with K.control_dependencies(update_ops):  # For TF
   1035             metric_fn.result()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py in decorated(metric_obj, *args, **kwargs)
     40         """Decorated function with `add_update()`."""
     41 
---> 42         update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     43         metric_obj.add_update(update_op)
     44         return update_op

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py in update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    316         y_pred, y_true = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(y_pred, y_true)
    317 
--> 318         matches = self._fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    319         return super(MeanMetricWrapper, self).update_state(
    320             matches, sample_weight=sample_weight)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py in __init__(self, thresholds, top_k, class_id, name, dtype)
   1419         default_threshold = 0.5 if top_k is None else metrics_utils.NEG_INF
   1420         self.thresholds = metrics_utils.parse_init_thresholds(
-> 1421             thresholds, default_threshold=default_threshold)
   1422         self.true_positives = self.add_weight(
   1423             'true_positives',

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py in parse_init_thresholds(thresholds, default_threshold)
    105 def parse_init_thresholds(thresholds, default_threshold=0.5):
    106     if thresholds is not None:
--> 107         assert_thresholds_range(to_list(thresholds))
    108     thresholds = to_list(default_threshold if thresholds is None else thresholds)
    109     return thresholds

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py in assert_thresholds_range(thresholds)
     96 def assert_thresholds_range(thresholds):
     97     if thresholds is not None:
---> 98         invalid_thresholds = [t for t in thresholds if t is None or t < 0 or t > 1]
     99     if invalid_thresholds:
    100         raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     96 def assert_thresholds_range(thresholds):
     97     if thresholds is not None:
---> 98         invalid_thresholds = [t for t in thresholds if t is None or t < 0 or t > 1]
     99     if invalid_thresholds:
    100         raise ValueError(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __bool__(self)
    651       `TypeError`.
    652     """
--> 653     raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
    654                     "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
    655                     "tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as "

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem please?

Comment: What is `n_steps_out`, and which line does it show error, give the complete error details

Comment: n_steps_out is the size of the prediction vector. In my case I want a single output prediction so n_steps_out = 1. I've just edited my post with the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change the metrics to accuracy :

```
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['Precision','Recall','AUC'])
```

Edit this to :

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: thank you. But why can't I use Precision as a metric? My dataset is very imbalanced that's why I wanted to check the precision.

Comment: According to my understanding, the label array and the predicted ones must have the same dimensions for the `Precision` metric. Have a look at the tf.keras.metrics.Precision documentation, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision